# What boundary conditions are used to CFD simulate airflow over an aerofoil?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, boundary-conditions, aerodynamics

As I understand it, in CFD, a boundary is the geometrical surface around the system  where you define the starting conditions for the simulation: For the analysis of fluid flow through a pipe a pipe it's the inlet, the outlet and the walls of the pipe.

When analysing airflow over a wing, the boundary would be the far field, a long way from the wing where there's no impact from the moving wing, but there is also the surface of the wing itself which is impermeable.

I haven't used CFD and was wondering how the wing boundary is defined and what parameters would have to be supplied to run the simulation.
I know it's a very broad question, so I'm not expecting a detailed answer, but one from a practitioner who might be able to provide an overview, or a link to an article that might yield an answer.

Comment: Have a look on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/238500/  and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225928/

Comment: It usually depends on the model you're using: Euler, Navier-Stokes, Averaged NS, LES,...?

Comment: @AlexTrounev It seems that the reference to NACA2415 retrieves the geometry of the wing, but what else defines the boundary conditions over the geometry? What is the granularity of the data? Where can I find these answers?

Comment: @basics Let me make a random selection - say "Averaged NS" (whatever that means!!) and then can you offer an answer to my question?

Comment: no random pick. Which system are you evaluating? If I know the system, I can suggest to you the right model to choose, and thus the appropriate boundary conditions of the appropriate model

Comment: I assume "Averaged NS" is the [Reynolds-Averaged Navier-Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds-averaged_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) equations. You might want to look at [boundary conditions in CFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_conditions_in_computational_fluid_dynamics) and [boundary conditions in fluid dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_conditions_in_fluid_dynamics).

Comment: @basics The system would be either the airflow over an aircraft wing at say 100kts in steady level flight at 5,000 ft or over a yacht's sail with an apparent wind of 20 kts at an apparent wind angle of 25°.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, I have seen that Wiki page and it doesn't help as it's very general and doesn't address the more specific example that I gave. (And whilst Wiki is a great source of general info, it's not really a reliable source of knowledge!)